# What version of Notepad++ should I use? Unicode or ANSI? I only do web design coding (PHP, CSS, and HTML)

Tags: notepad++

What version of [Notepad++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad%2B%2B) should I use? Unicode or ANSI?

I only do web design coding ([PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP), [CSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets), and [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML)).

Answer (score 4):

Unicode, for sure.

If you are only doing English-language sites it doesn't *really* matter, but Unicode supports just about any language and encoding out there, whereas ANSI is limited more or less to the English language or languages which don't have "strange letters" (like á, í, ö, þ, ð and such).

So when in doubt, use Unicode. Switch to ANSI only if you have problems with the Unicode version.

UTF-8 is something you may run into quite a bit, which is the encoding of Unicode, and for your purposes you may consider them the same thing. So you always want UTF-8/Unicode unless it gives you problems, and even then it's preferable to fix those problems rather than reverting to a more limited encoding... and that limited encoding may also cause you problems anyway.

If you are doing development for other languages (French, Spanish or whatever), you may *need* the Unicode version.

EDIT: Even if you don't include any non-English language in your code itself, there are mechanisms which detect the encoding type of your code, so it may still matter. Same rules apply; Unicode/UTF-8 unless it gives you problems, and then first try fixing those problems and if you can't, try ANSI knowing that it may give you problems with other languages than English.

Comment: Yeah, UTF-8 should be the best choice at this time.

Answer (score 2):

I use the ANSI version because I need the TextFX plugin. It only works with the ANSI ver.

Comment: Would you be able to elaborate?  I've been using TextFX for years with the Unicode version without any issues (though I can't attest to trying every available TextFX command).